# preg_replace remove only part of a string but leave the rest using PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to do a replace within a string in PHP.  How do you delete the part that is only in the group in PHP?

```
<font.+?(size.+?.)>
```

I want to remove size=x where ever it in. The problem is I cannot get the

```
 $text = preg_replace("<font.+?(size.+?.)>","",$text);
```

function to work.

Example source of this

```
<font style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);" size="2"><strong><u>text</u></strong></font>
<font size="2">more text</font>
```

into this

```
<font style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);" ><strong><u>text</u></strong></font>
<font>more text</font>
```

I am trying to say.  Where ever there is a font tag and if I see size-anything remove the size attribute, but leave everything else intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution, but to answer your question:

```
$html = <<<END
<font style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);" size="2"><strong><u>text</u></strong></font>
<font size="2">more text</font>
END;

$text = preg_replace('/(<font.*?)(size\s*=[^\s>]*)([^>]*)>/si', '\1\3>', $html);
var_dump($text);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($htmlstring);
$x = new DOMXPath($dom);
$list = $x->query('//font/@size');
for($i = $list->length-1;$i>=0;$i--){
    $attr = $list->item($i);
    $attr->ownerElement->removeAttributeNode($attr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I wasn't aware of the DOMDocument() class.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a poor way of doing HTML manipulation, but that said, the general technique to do this kind of regex matching and partial replacement is to match:

```
(<font.+?)(size.+?.)(>)
\________/\________/\_/
    1         2      3
```

And then replace with

```
$1$3
```

This substitutes into the replacement backreferences to what group 1 and group 3 matched, leaving group 2 out, effectively deleting what group 2 matched.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Brackets for Grouping and Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: While in essence the use of capturing subpatterns would work, the regex itself is of course insufficient. `Size` not as a last attribute, `size` somewhere in a attribute value, `>` somewhere in a attribute value, `size` in _another_ element after the font tag, etc.

Comment: @Wrikken: correct, hence the disclaimer about regex for HTML. If somehow a pattern that works can be found (easier said than done), then the methodology described here can be applied.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I am not modifying the actual html page.  Someone has sorted data in a database and I need to strip out tags in order to override it with custom css so when it is displayed in the page the <font> element will take on the look and feel we are looking for.    Long story...

Thank you again for all your help adn answers...